# Timer Gets Faster and Faster

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a jquery plugin for my website, here is a snippet:

```
(function($){
    var options;
    var fqTimer;
    var counter = 1;

    $.fn.jsSlideShow = function(settings){
        options = $.extend({
            frequency: 3000,
            speed: "slow",
            images: [],
            position: "center center"
        }, settings);
        addImages();
        doFade();
        return this;
    };
    function doFade(){
        fqTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            fade();
        }, options.frequency);
    }
    // other functions
});
```

It works, but I am having a problem. I have this code in jquery's ajax success callback:

```
$("#player").jsSlideShow({
    images: imgs
});
```

But what happens, is that now my `doFade()` function gets called faster, and every time my ajax success is called `doFade()` gets even faster. Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Here is my ajax call:

```
success: function(data){
    var player = $("<div>").attr("id", "player").addClass("jsSlideShow");
    $("#page").html(player);
    var imgs = new Array();
    for(i in data){
        file = data[i]["filename"] + ".jpg";
        imgs.push("/media/gallery/" + file);
    }

    $("#player").jsSlideShow({
        images: imgs
    });
}
```

**EDIT: New Working copy**

Here is the full plugin:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.jsSlideShow = function(settings){
        var options;
        var fqTimer = null;
        clearTimeout(fqTimer);
        var counter = 1;
        var jsSlider = $(this);
        options = $.extend({
            frequency: 3000,
            speed: "slow",
            images: [],
            position: "center center"
        }, settings);
        addImages();
        doFade();

        function addImages(){
            var hide = false;
            jsSlider.html("");
            for(i in options.images){
                var div = $("<div>").attr("id", "jsSlideShow-" + i).addClass("jsSlideShow-img-block").css({
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%",
                    backgroundImage: "url('" + options.images[i] + "')",
                    backgroundPosition: options.position,
                    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                    position: "absolute"
                });
                if(hide){
                    div.css({display: "none"});
                }
                hide = true;
                jsSlider.append(div);
            }
        }

        function doFade(){
            fqTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                fade();
            }, options.frequency);
        }

        function fade(){
            current = jsSlider.children("div.jsSlideShow-img-block:nth-child(" + counter + ")");
            current.fadeOut(options.speed);
            counter++;
            if(counter === options.images.length + 1){
                counter = 1;
            }
            current = jsSlider.children("div.jsSlideShow-img-block:nth-child(" + counter + ")");
            current.fadeIn(options.speed, function(){
                doFade();
            });
        }


        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Well, whenever you are calling `.jsSlideShow`, a new timeout is created. So you are probably creating multiple "concurrent" timeouts which work on the same elements and therefore somehow effect each other.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah... So, how can I create a timeout for each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from what I understand, I dont see any line of code to stop previous timers that were setup by previously applied plugins, so I believe that they all stack up and the more you have at different intervals, the faster they get.

Now, what you should be doing is detect if the plugin was previously applied on that element and if so, clear previously set timeouts.

However, the way you designed your plugin, the `options` and other variables are shared, so they will be replaced everytime you apply the plugin on different elements. You will have to change this as well...

Comment: yes it works now after my edits, `var jsSlider = $(this);` created an internal copy of the item, so now I use that when referencing the current dom item instead of searching for it (if that makes sense)